# Translate input text field without pressing shift key

Tags: javascript, php, translate

I have two input fields here

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control formRow--input js-input" name="product_name" id="product_name" placeholder="Product Name (ENG)" required>
<input type="text"  class="form-control formRow--input js-input" id="product_name_mal" name="product_name_mal" placeholder="Product Name (MAL)" >
```

When i type the product name in English in the first input field and press the shift key, it get translated to malayalam in the second input field.

This is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "transliteration"});
</script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function OnLoad() {                
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage:
        google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage:
        [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.MALAYALAM],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };

    var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
    control.makeTransliteratable(["product_name_mal"]);
    var keyVal = 32; // Space key
    $("#product_name").on('keydown', function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 32) {
            var engText = $("#product_name").val() + " ";
            var engTextArray = engText.split(" ");
            $("#product_name_mal").val($("#product_name_mal").val() + engTextArray[engTextArray.length-2]);

            document.getElementById("product_name_mal").focus();
            $("#product_name_mal").trigger ( {
                type: 'keypress', keyCode: keyVal, which: keyVal, charCode: keyVal
            } );
        }
    });

    $("#product_name_mal").bind ("keyup",  function (event) {
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#product_name").val($("#product_name").val() + " "); document.getElementById("product_name").focus()},0);
    });
} 

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
```

I want the second input field to get converted to Malayalam without pressing the shift key. I'm not much into JS. Can someone please help me do it?

Comment: Hi, can you create a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: You can fire an onchange event on ```product name(Eng)``` using ```javascript``` or ```jquery```. If ```product name(Eng)``` changes, ```Product name(mal)``` also changes.

Comment: `$("#product_name").change(function() { console.log($("#product_name")) });`

Comment: You are wrong in saying it works when you "press the shift key", the code you shared is using keycode-32 which is a SPACE KEY not Shift Key :)